# Unusual date format

Tags: json, date, datetime

I'm meant to parsing some open data, it has an unsual date format scheme which I've never encountered before and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas that might shed some light on it, here is an example:

```
"IncorporationDate":41137,
"Accounts": {"AccountRefDay":31,
             "AccountRefMonth":8,
             "NextDueDate":42155,
             "LastMadeUpDate":41517,
             "AccountCategory":"DORMANT"
            },
"Returns":{"NextDueDate":42260,
           "LastMadeUpDate":41867
        }
```

Any ideas welcome!

EDIT:

Thanks for pointing me in the direction of excel dates, would nayone happen to have a function in JS(preferably)for converting to ISO 8601.

Thanks

Comment: I think you will need to get in touch with the data owner or source. Any body else will just guess the format unless it is actually following some standard (something I am ofcourse not aware of).

Comment: Days since 1900? I'm gonna run some calculations...

Comment: Looks like days since `30 December 1899` (app I used to check could be a rounding error, so maybe consider `31 Dec 1899`)

Comment: Looks like it might be related to Excel, which stores dates as the number of days since 0/1/1900 (so a value of 1 is 1/1/1900 and 41137 would be 16/08/2012). In these situations though, to be safe, you should consult either the spec that relates to the data, or in the absence of that, the person that is providing the data

Answer (score 5):

Dont know this is the right format or not, but when copied those numbers to EXCEL and converted to Date and I got this

```
41137   8/16/2012
42155   5/31/2015
41517   8/31/2013

42260   9/13/2015
41867   8/16/2014
```

and this date `8/31/2013` seems to be referring to `AccountRefDay` & `AccountRefMonth`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Cortex just got some fresh new information.

Comment: Nice catch the excel. 1+

Answer (score 2):

> Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of
>   days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day:
>   ddddd.tttttt . This is called a serial date, or serial date-time.

---

Convert the excel date to php date using:

```
function excelDateToDate($readDate){
    $phpexcepDate = $readDate-25569; //to offset to Unix epoch
    $timestamp = strtotime("+$phpexcepDate days", mktime(0,0,0,1,1,1970) / 1000);
    return date("d-m-Y", $timestamp); //  if needed, add hours, minutes, etc.
}

echo excelDateToDate(41137);
```

---

Output:

```
16-08-2012
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/6udwhC

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Cortex just got some fresh new information.